# Colon after method declaration?

Tags: php, php-7

```
public function getRecords(int $id): array;
```

Hi, can someone tell me what colon is doing here, in this method declaration inside PHP interface? Is this PHP 7 syntax and what array is meaning here? Method must return array or something else?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes it's new syntax introduced in PHP 7 to declare the method returns an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: Just to note the `;` is not new to PHP 7 correct? That is needed on any method defined in an interface. The new syntax in the question is `: array` for the return type declaration.

Answer (score 56):

These are called [Return Type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) in PHP7. It indicates the type of value that the function returns, and it's not limited to arrays. For example, you can use `float`, `int` or even your own class:

```
class MyClass { }

function something(): MyClass {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

These are not just for readability. If the function returns a type other than that indicated, the value will be coerced into the indicated type. If it cannot be coerced, or strict mode is enabled, a Type Error will be thrown.

Comment: Appreciate the further explanation.