# PHP syntax - what's this?

Tags: php, syntax

It's almost impossible for me to search for an answer to this as I don't know what this syntax is called.

I have a server running a relatively old version of PHP (5.5.38) and I'm getting parse errors when I run a file that has the following:

```
public function foo(): array
{
```

...specifically the `: array` suffix.

Can anyone tell me what this syntax is called (so I can research further) and which PHP version introduced it?

Comment: Well I've seen these before function arguments, but never after the arguments list. New to me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration <-- Return type declaration, added in PHP 7.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40346754/6309457

Comment: Thank you, all. To downvoter - I'm not sure what you would suggest I should have done. I had no idea what it was called, which makes it rather tricky to search. To closer - it's very clear what I'm asking. I will mark the question as duplicate (to the one @DevsiOdedra linked to.)

Comment: Well, search for : after functions and you'll find a lot of informations about the : ;)

Answer (score 5):

This was added in PHP 7, they're called return type declarations.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration